# how to use '^' char in a replace expression

Tags: sed

I want to use sed to replace some strings containing '^' in a text file

The original string (" are part of the string)

```
"POINT(5.94462 45.569924)^^geo:wktLiteral"
```

the expected substituted string

```
"POINT(5.94462 45.569924)"^^geo:wktLiteral
```

I've tried

```
sed -i 's/\^\^geo:wktLiteral\"/\"\^\^geo:wktLiteral/' myFile
```

or

```
sed -i 's/\x5e\x5egeo:wktLiteral\"/\"\x5e\x5egeo:wktLiteral/' myFile
```

these two solutions do not work.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: `sed -i 's/\^\^geo:wktLiteral"/"&/' file`?

Comment: I've found a solution working `sed  's/)^^^^geo:wktLiteral\"/)\"^^^^geo:wktLiteral/'` but may be there is a better one.

Comment: Are you using *sed for Windows* in the console?

Comment: Why do you use `^` to escape `^`? Please explain.

Comment: Yes I'm using sed in a [ConEnum](https://conemu.github.io/) windows terminal and the response you gave me does not work  I get the following error message `sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated \`s' command`

Comment: Ok, this is not standard sed. I downloaded the terminal, but it contains no `sed` :( Although, since I installed WSL Linux 18.04, I can switch to that environment, and the regular syntax works there.

Comment: Yes, I didn't made the install on this computer so I don't know where this sed version comes form. I've tried your response with WLS. The reponse you gave almots works but there is still the ending `"` :      `   edytem:location_wkt   "POINT(5.94462 45.569924)"^^geo:wktLiteral" .`

Comment: Yes, it should be `sed -i 's/\(\^\^geo:wktLiteral\)"/"\1/' file`

Comment: You're right it's work fine on WSL (but not in my ugly ConEmu windows terminal . Thx ! Do you have any good pointer to understand the reg expr you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch to the WSL Linux terminal, you can use a simpler

```sh
sed -i 's/\(\^\^geo:wktLiteral\)"/"\1/' file
```

*Details*

- `\(\^\^geo:wktLiteral\)` - Group 1: `^^geo:wktLiteral` string
- `"` - a `"` char
- `"\1` - replacement: a `"` char and Group 1 value.